# Delete [mvvmcross-community]?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, burninate-request

Can we get [mvvmcross-community](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mvvmcross-community) deleted?

It's a duplicate of [mvvmcross](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mvvmcross) - and every question posted with "-community" is also posted without it.

Sorry this isn't a very detailed request... but I'm actually a bit lost why this Tag exists - not sure I see any reason/benefit from it.

Comment: There is but *one* post that uses `mvvmcross-community` without `mvvmcross` and that looks like it was a mistake. I say burninate the thing.

Comment: The only reference to 'community' with 'mvvcross' I can find is a [SQLite plugin](https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross-SQLite); it doesn't appear to be a specific distict concept within that tag.

Answer (score 4):

I could find no evidence that `mvvcross-community` was a separate concept. None of the posts with `mvvmcross-community` ever used terminology that indicated a distict 'community' concept was being discussed, the only Google result for `mvvcross` and `community` is a [SQLite plugin](https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross-SQLite) that uses the word *Community* in it's project title. Only one tagged post was discussing that plugin. The tag had no wiki explaining its use either.

All but one question that was tagged with that tag was *also* tagged with [mvvcross](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mvvcross), where the omission of the latter was clearly a mistake.

As such, the tag had no meaning and no distinct I could discern. I've burninated it:

[image: tag burninated]

Comment: @Stuart: that, my friend, is [Trogdor the Burninator](http://knowyourmeme.com/memes/trogdor)!

Comment: Thanks - that music video now bookmarked alongside a certain Oatmeal Pterodactyl :)